# Is there a way to add custom keyboard shortcuts to Vim for running numerous commands?

Tags: c++, vim, compilation, shortcut

I'm having the following issue - whenever I finish writing some C++ code in Vim and want to compile and run it, I have to:

1. Exit insert mode
2. Save the file using the command `:w`
3. Write `:! g++ *.cpp -o programName; ./programName` in order to compile and run at once

After inputting the last two commands once, I obviously make use of the upper arrow key on the keyboard to get the last few commands instead of writting them down again and again on future compilations and runs.

But it's still kind of slow to me. So I was wondering if there's some sort of way to maybe create a keyboard shortcut which inputs these last two commands or even does all the three things at once!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `map` to map keys to commands. `nmap` for normal mode, `imap` for insert mode etc

```
map <key> command
```

the `cpp` compiling you mentioned should go like:

```
autocmd FileType cpp nmap <buffer> <F5> :w<bar>!g++ -o %:r % && ./%:r<CR>
```

Add this command to your `vimrc` and will compile and run the current cpp file.
`FileType cpp`- detects the `cpp` file directly, (*no need of manual regex*).
`nmap`- used for mapping key while normal mode.
`buffer`- for the current buffer (*in case of multiple splits*).
`<F5>`- for mapping the 'F5' key.
And the command that executes is: `:w | !g++ -o %:r % && ./%:r<CR>`

In the above command, `%` is the file name (*with extension*), while `%:r` is the file name(*without extension*),
 `<CR>` stands for the "Enter" button (*Carriage Return*)

Comment: After adding - **autocmd FileType cpp nmap <buffer> <F5> :w<bar>!g++ -o %:r % && ./%:r<CR>** to my .vimrc and pressing F5 while in a .cpp file, nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: one flaw about the above method is that you should make sure you are opening the file from the directory its in and not from some other, for e.g: `vim path/to/file` not recommended, `cd path/to/dir`, `vim filename`, this is preferable.

Comment: Yeah, I always do it like that.

Comment: This is the way you map keys, It should work, maybe try restarting vim, i guess.

Comment: What does autocmd mean? Also what do you mean by *And the command to execute is: :w | !g++ -o %:r % && ./%:r<CR>*? Do I have to manually execute this every time? Is all that's needed for me to add the line that starts with *autocmd* to my .vimrc?

Comment: `autocmd` for automatic execution (here matching `Filetype` to `cpp` and `map` key) just add this to your `.vimrc`: `autocmd FileType cpp nmap <buffer> <F5> :w<bar>!g++ -o %:r % && ./%:r<CR>`, restart vim and you are good to go. Please reply if it doesn't work, which it should.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, it works! It turned out that I had forgotten to press the fn(function key) on my laptop's keyboard while pressing F5... Just one more quick thing. How can I change the mapping from F5 to Ctrl+Esc(I've swapped Esc with Caps lock on my laptop, but I assume I should still use Esc instead of Caps when modifiying in .vimrc)?

Comment: instead of `<F5>`, do `<C-esc>`.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how the autocmd line would be in the .vimrc if I wanted after saving with **:w** to run **:! g++ *.cpp *.h; ./a.out** instead of **:! g++ *.cpp -o programName; ./programName** like it was so far?

Answer (score 4):

## Speeding up what you've used

If you `:set autowrite`, Vim will automatically persist the source file before invoking an external command (`:!`).

You can repeat the last external command via `:!!` (old vi trick), or / and then repeat the last Ex command via `@:` (still two keypresses less).

However, this doesn't scale, so you might be better off with a *mapping*.

## Mapping

As this is specific to C++, I would advise you to define a *buffer-local mapping*, in a *filetype plugin*:

You can define that for certain filetypes by prepending `:autocmd Filetype cpp ...`, and put that into your `~/.vimrc`. But that gets unwieldy as you add mappings and other settings for various filetypes. Better put the commands into `~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp_mappings.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.)

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :update<Bar>!g++ -o %:r % && ./%:r<CR>
```

#### Notes

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- `:update` is a variant of `:write` that only performs a write if there indeed are unpersisted changes; so, it's slightly more efficient.
- For the `%:r` placeholders (that make the mapping independent of the current filename), see `:help cmdline-special`.